# Modifying a file in two branches then merging both with master

Tags: git

I'm a bit new to git, so I just want to ensure that I won't mess everything up.

I created a new branch (let's call cinnamon) and started editing a file (applejack) to add some minor functionality.

However, my partner now wants different, completely unrelated, functionality. This functionality requires me to edit the aforementioned file, applejack.

If I create another new branch (sugar) and edit the same file (applejack) but in a different part of the file, can I merge both cinnamon and sugar with master? Will the master version of applejack be updated with the code from each branch in the right places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to make changes in different part of the same file in two different child branches (sugar and cinnamon here ) of master and then merge them both into the master at a later stage , git's auto merge will not complain and do a plain merge.

```
git checkout -b cinnamon
vim applejack (make changes in function a or line 1 as you said)
git add applejack
git commit
git checkout master
git checkout -b sugar
vim applejack (make changes in function b or line 50 as you mentioned)
git commit
git checkout master
git merge sugar [Will auto merge]
git merge cinnamon [Now this too will auto merge without conflicts since you touched some other part of the file]
```

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand completely. Let's say I change line 1 in sugar and line 50 in cinnamon. After I merge both with master, will the updated file have the changes in both line 1 and 50?

Comment: I explained it above with the commands itself. Does that help ?